# How to repeat my "if" and "elif" statements after my "else" statement

Tags: python

How do I make it so that it goes back to the previous commands after `else` statement

```
Name = input("Please insert your Name = ")
Male = "Male"
Female = "Female"

Gender = input("Are you male or female = ")

if Gender == Male:
    print(Name)
    print(Gender)
    print("he/him")

elif Gender == Female:
    print(Name)
    print(Gender)
    print("she/her")

else: Gender != Male or Female
print("Please try again")
print("NOTE: Check if answer contains capital letter")
input("Are you male or female = ")
```

[image]

Comment: try look at  `while(true)` loop in python. refer: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

Comment: `while True` use

Comment: While loops trump memory performance.

Comment: For extra points use `match`

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    name = input("Please insert your Name = ")
    gender = input("Are you male or female = ")

    if gender == "Male":
        print(name, '\n', "Male", "\n", "he/him")
    elif gender == "Female":
        print(name, '\n', "Female", "\n", "she/her")
    else:
        print("Please try again")
        print("NOTE: Check if answer contains capital letter")
        input("Are you male or female = ")
```

if you mean reenter gender when the gender is mistake,use this:

```
name = input("Please insert your Name = ")
while True:
    gender = input("Are you male or female = ")

    if gender == "Male":
        print(name, '\n', "Male", "\n", "he/him")
    elif gender == "Female":
        print(name, '\n', "Female", "\n", "she/her")
    else:
        print("Please try again")
        print("NOTE: Check if answer contains capital letter")
        continue
    break
```